# how to insert "between yyyy-mm-dd and yyyy-mm-dd" into a prepared statement?

Tags: mysql, date, prepared-statement

I am trying to return a tuples within a certain year and I can't get the prepared statement to return anything but an empty set. Here is the parameter I call it with: year.valueOf("2014-01-01"); not sure if that's already the problem, and this is just for testing it's normally a value from a textfield.

```
public List<Sales> findYear(Date date) {
    try {
        List<Sales> listSales = new ArrayList<>();
```

I tried it with two parameters so this is just the test version.
When I hard code both dates into the prepared statement it works, so the method itself seems fine. Adding ' ' around the ? makes no difference.

```
        PreparedStatement ps = ConnectDB
                .getConnection()
                .prepareStatement(
                        "select * from sales where sale_date between ? and '2014-12-30'");
        ps.setDate(1, date);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            Sales s = new Sales();
            s.setEmpno(rs.getInt("empno"));
            s.setOutno(rs.getInt("outno"));
            s.setPno(rs.getInt("pno"));
            s.setCno(rs.getInt("cno"));
            s.setOno(rs.getInt("ono"));
            s.setQty(rs.getInt("qty"));
            s.setSale_date(rs.getDate("sale_date"));
            s.setSale_time(rs.getTime("sale_time"));
            listSales.add(s);
        }
        return listSales;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/19584099/2055998

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"select * from sales where sale_date between ?-?-? and ?-?-?"
```

Then set the dates:

```
prepare.setInt(1, day1);
prepare.setInt(2, month1);
prepare.setInt(3, year1);
prepare.setInt(4, day2);
prepare.setInt(5, month2);
prepare.setInt(6, year3);
```

You can also turn a date into a string:

```
"select * from sales where sale_date between ? and ?"
...

String date1Str = SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(date1);
String date2Str = SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(date2);

prepare.setString(1, date1Str);
prepare.setString(2, date2Str);
```

---

Expanded example:

```
try {    
        PreparedStatement ps = ConnectDB.getConnection()
                        .prepareStatement(
                        "select * from sales where sale_date between ? and ?");
        ps.setDate(1, date);
        // whatever date2 is
        ps.setDate(2, date2);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
                Sales s = new Sales();
                s.setEmpno(rs.getInt("empno"));
                s.setOutno(rs.getInt("outno"));
                s.setPno(rs.getInt("pno"));
                s.setCno(rs.getInt("cno"));
                s.setOno(rs.getInt("ono"));
                s.setQty(rs.getInt("qty"));
                s.setSale_date(rs.getDate("sale_date"));
                s.setSale_time(rs.getTime("sale_time"));
                listSales.add(s);
        }
        return listSales;

} catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        return null;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but is there no way to make it look closer to this (obviously this version doesn't work):                                                     "select * from sales where sale_date between' "?" ' and ' "?" ' ");
   ps.setDate(1, date);
   ps.setDate(2, date2);

Comment: @recycledElectrons just copy and paste my changes into the code you have supplied above. The `select * ...` goes in the same place and the string declarations can go anywhere before `prepare.setString(X, dateXStr)`. If you really need me to I can add it.

Comment: Actually, that might be helpful, I am running on little sleep. Also, so I just don't use the java.sql.Date object , and just drop in strings? And, thanks for the help!

Comment: wow that was easy, thanks for the help, it was embarrassingly easy doing it with strings.