# How to use between in prepared query statement

Tags: sql

For example, if we have to find some data from a table which lies between two specific date, that we write query like this:

```
Select * from TableName where Date lies between '01-01-2000' and '01-01-2002'
```

I just want to know how to use this query in PreparedQueryStatement?

Comment: what kind of code have you tried?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Searching between dates in SQL with JDBC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19583806/searching-between-dates-in-sql-with-jdbc) Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22309455/select-statement-between-two-java-sql-date

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a string with placeholders and then pass instances of `java.sql.Date` to the `PreparedStatement`

```
String query = "Select * from TableName where some_date_column between ? and ?";
java.sql.Date dateOne = java.sql.Date.valueOf(LocalDate.of(2000, 1, 1));
java.sql.Date dateTwo = java.sql.Date.valueOf(LocalDate.of(2002, 1, 1));

PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(query);
pstmt.setDate(1, dateOne);
pstmt.setDate(2, dateTwo);
ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
... process the result ...
```

**Never** pass dates (or timestamps or numbers) as strings!

---

Note that the SQL `BETWEEN` operator *includes* both values. The expression

```
some_date_column BETWEEN date '2000-01-01' and date '2002-01-01'
```

is equivalent to:

```
    some_date_column >= date '2000-01-01' 
and some_date_column <= date '2002-01-01'
```

If you want to *exclude* rows from '2002-01-01' you need:

```
some_date_column BETWEEN date '2000-01-01' and date '2001-12-31'
```