# Get elements where date is within the same week in H2

Tags: java, sql, timestamp, h2

I've been trying to get all the elements from a table where, given a certain date, it gives me all the elements that belong to the same week.
I know it has something to do with the WEEK function, but I've tried some querys and I don't know where I am going wrong.

All help is appreciated, thanks in advance :)

Comment: Show the code that you have tried.

Comment: @michalk I've been trying some queries, but I haven't saved them anywhere, since they didn't work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [*Searching between dates in SQL with JDBC?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19583806/642706) and [many others](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=java+dates+jdbc+sql).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be easier to find the first and the last day of the week in Java and then query H2 about elements between those two dates. I hope you’re already using `LocalDate` in Java (you should), then look into either `WeekFields` or `TemporalAdjusters`, which you find more convenient and appropriate.

Here are links to documentation of [`WeekFields`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/temporal/WeekFields.html) and [`TemporalAdjusters`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html).